# Fail to build Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I reopened an old project with a wcf cloud service and im getting these errors:

> Error 113 The setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.Refresh' for role WCFService is specified in the service configuration file, but it is not declared in the service definition file. C:\Users\Etc\ - Cloud\Cloud Service\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
>
> Error 114 The setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.WaitForConnectivity' for role WCFService is specified in the service configuration file, but it is not declared in the service definition file. C:\Users\Etc\ Service\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

And more 10 errors like this, my ServiceConfiguration file

```
 <Role name="WCFService">
   <Instances count="1" />
   <ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"    value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.Refresh" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.WaitForConnectivity" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.Upgrade" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.EnableDomainJoin" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainFQDN" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainControllerFQDN" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainAccountName" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainPassword" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainOU" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.Administrators" value="" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.DomainSiteName" value="" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
<Role name="WorkerRoleService">
 <Instances count="1" />
 <ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
 </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

And my ServiceDefinition file:

```
<WebRole name="WCFGuazzelliService" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
 <Sites>
   <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  <Import moduleName="Connect" />
</Imports>
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="WCFService.svclog" sizeInMB="1000"    cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
</LocalResources>
</WebRole>
<WorkerRole name="WorkerRoleService" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
 <Imports>
   <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  </Imports>
</WorkerRole>
```

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's configuration that is using **Windows Azure Connect** which was retired on 3 July 2013.

Details on what to do found in this post: [Windows Azure Connect Has Been Retired](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2013/07/09/windows-azure-connect-has-been-retired.aspx)

If you're not using it, those configuration items (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.Refresh.*`) can probably be removed.

Comment: @Bredan - Do you know what is the new way to connect?